# From text to XML

Tags: c++, xml, dom, sax, libxml2

I want to know if there is any way to create XML files from `.txt` by using `c++` and `libxml` ?

input file looks like that :

```
"< url   >..........< / url>
<description>His work points a way forward for saving the oceans' health -- and humanity's.</description>
<keywords>fish,health,mission blue,oceans,science</keywords>
<talkid>899</talkid>
<title>Stephen Palumbi: Following the mercury trail</title>
<transcript>
It can be a very complicated thing, the ocean.
And it can be a very complicated thing, what human health is. " 

after transcript I have a huge text
after the tag </transcript>
```

another bloc starts with the same structure 
what I want is structuring the whole thing and regroup the meta data together because after that I need to process the text separately.

Comment: What does this text file contains? what format?

Comment: The .txt is structured in this way : 

<title>........</title>

<description1>........</description>
this is the metadata the text is between the tag transcript
<transcript>........</transcript>
a lot of text here
and then the same bloc of metadatem actuall in the same .txt I have many blocs of txt
what I want is for the xml file regrouping all the metadata between <information>.....the same metadata  </information>
and keeping the text like it is, I want to do that for all blocs of text

Comment: So, it's a valid XML?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Either (a) You already have valid XML in the .txt file in which case what is it you are trying to do?, or (b) You have non-XML in the text file, in which case you need to explain your question properly.

Comment: Not really since it is many blocs and each one looks like an xml

Comment: I have a .txt the problem is that I want an xml output 
the input is .txt which contains some tags to indicate <title>
and <description>
actually it is a big corpus and it is hundred thousand lines of many blocs each bloc contains those tags.
what is sure is that it is not an xml but a txt file

Comment: @mimi it is irrelevant what the "file" is, all that matters is the content *inside* the file. Your comment above is very hard to decipher. Please edit the question with a sample of the data in your .txt file, and an example of what you want it to look like after you're done.

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "regrouping all the metadata between <information> ..... the same metadata </information>"? - this is too confusing. Please edit your question with a clear example.

Comment: Also, why are you opening a tag with with a number - <description1> but closing a tag without a number - </description>?

Comment: that was a typing error (for description)

Comment: Ok, you've given an example of the input file, now give an example of what you want the output to look like. Also, I don't see any <information></information> tags in your example, that you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: What I want is :
<doc>
  <url>
      <httpaddress>
            <topdomain> .......</topdomain>
      </httpaddress>
  </url>
 <corpus>
   my whole text which were betwwen <transcript in the input>
 </corpus>
</doc>

Comment: And I want to do that for all the blocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to understand what is a valid xml document? In short it must satisfy a DTD or a schema (an xml schema, a relaxng schema, schematron or other constraints) to be valid.

Judging from the wording of the question, most probably it asks:

"How to make sure a file contains a well-formed XML document, and read those elements? It does not matter whether the XML is in a file with .text extension or something else as mentioned in uʍop ǝpısdn answer".

The answer is that an XML document is well-formed if it can be parsed successfully by a compliant XML parser. So let say if your text file contains a well formed XML, it can be read by any compliant XML parser ...

You can try it yourself by reading your "text" file with

```
http://www.xmlsoft.org/
http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/
```

It is also worthy to look at

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp
```

Comment: If it is exactly what you were looking for, you can mark my answer as "answer" for this question, by clicking the Tick sign.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a file ends in `.txt` or `.xml` or `.whatnot` is irrelevant.

Adding `.*` to file names is just a convention. A way of saving you the time of opening each file to verify the format, or a hint to a program so that it knows what it's dealing with. *Hint* is the keyword -- files can have arbitrary names, they are not enforced into following the convention.

Opening a valid `xml` formatted file is the same process, whether the file name ends in `.xml` or not.

## Edit

You say the file has a number of `XML` blocks, but is not `XML` per se -- `XML` does require a single outermost tag. Just add `<root>` and `</root>` at the beginning and end of your file. Rename it to `xml` if you want.

In other words, the question you should be asking yourself is how to feed your `XML` parser additional data before feeding it the file, and after. Something like this:

```
parser.feed('<root>')
parser.feed(read('file.txt'))
parser.feed('</root>')
```

Comment: Yes like JBentley said, I need to process this data, it is a text file and I want to create an xml file, I explained the whole structure on the comment above,

Comment: @mimi You explained it in a very confusing way. Please edit your question to give *before* and *after* examples of what the actual data would like like, rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: @Mimi I'm with Bentley here, you may want to ask a different question with better phrasing and the examples he mentions. This one is confusing, and will have little future value even if we're able to help you.

Comment: Okay,
I will try to see how to do that 
Thanks all for your help